# Storage duration when calling constructor from another function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, lifetime

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct matrix {
    size_t nrow;
    size_t ncol;
    double *data;
};
```

and a corresponding constructor:

```
struct matrix *matrix_create(const size_t nrow, const size_t ncol)
{
    struct matrix *m;

    m = malloc(sizeof(struct matrix));
    if (!m) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    m->data = malloc(sizeof(double) * nrow * ncol);
    if (!m->data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    m->nrow = nrow;
    m->ncol = ncol;

    return m;
}
```

Now say I want to have another function that calls the constructor and returns a pointer to the `struct`:

```
struct matrix *matrix_dostuff(const struct matrix *m1, const struct matrix *m2)
{
    struct matrix *dostuff =
        matrix_create(m1->nrow * m2->nrow, m1->ncol * m2->ncol);

    /* do stuff */

    return dostuff;
}
```

Is this well-defined behaviour aka is `dostuff` guaranteed to exist after the function returns?

Comment: C does not have constructors. Their semantics are different from functions.

Comment: Yes, I know. If it bothers you, mentally substitute "`C` function in the style of a constructor".

Comment: That is a factory function. A constructor is a method bound to an existing (but uninitialized) object.

Comment: @Olaf, please, feel free to edit.

Comment: Doing OOP in C, this is the most commonly used form of a "constructor replacement". It's technically *just a function*, neither a factory function (that would give you potentially different concrete types) nor a constructor (that would be called automatically after allocation). Semantically, it is a constructor that (as an implementation detail) does its own allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is not undefined behaviour.

In your code, `dostuff` is holding a pointer returned by `malloc()`. It's lifetime is spanned until deallocated manually , like using `free()`. So, returning `dostuff` and using it later is all good.